# CSV Helper Exception MissingMethodException: Constructor 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile()' was not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, csvhelper

After updating CsvHelper multiple versions to the latest version 21.1.0 I am receiving the exception below when trying to read CSV files submitted via a form:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
MissingMethodException: Constructor 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile()' was not found.
CsvHelper.ObjectCreator.GetConstructorNotFoundException(Type type, Type[] argTypes)

ReaderException: An unexpected error occurred.
IReader state:
ColumnCount: 0
CurrentIndex: 9
HeaderRecord:
[""]
IParser state:
ByteCount: 0
CharCount: 877
Row: 2
RawRow: 2
Count: 55
RawRecord:
12345,12345,jon,,doe,doe,,,,,test@example.com,Female,4/21/2014,example,example,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,jane,doe,9999999999,test@example.com,,111,S,Main,,St,City,CA,90210,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

The current index of 9 is a column where I want to accept a blank string and convert it to a a null value. In the model its setup as type string. There are multiple columns like this that all seem to have a problem after updating. These are optional fields.

Here is an abbreviated version of the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> FileImport(FileViewModel fileViewModel)
{
IFormFile file = fileViewModel.File;
var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            MissingFieldFound = null,
            TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
            ShouldSkipRecord = record => record.All(string.IsNullOrEmpty)
        };

        var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfiguration);

        csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<CustomMapProfile>();

        var test = csvReader.GetRecords<RowViewModel>().ToList(); //FAILS HERE WHILE DEBUGGING
    }
}
        
}
```

Map Profile Example

```
    public CustomMapProfile()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to show `CustomMapProfile` and `RowViewModel`. I am assuming you have an `IFormFile` as a property in `RowViewModel` which obviously wouldn't work because you can't instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The below solution is tested and working perfectly.

It looks like your model or view model contains IFromFile interface. example below

```
[NotMapped]
public IFormFile logoFile { get; set; }
```

1. First remove IFromFile from model or view model
2. For file upload use IFromFile as argument in controller

`public async Task<IActionResult> Create(MyModel model,IFormFile logoFile) { }`

1. Remove default scaffolded input razor tag with below input tag

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="logoFile"/>
<form/>
```